# how to get count in groupby mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

hy..I have table like this
**1.tb_result**

```
id | test_id    | result
====================
1  | 1 | A
2  | 1 | A
2  | 2 | A
3  | 3 | B
```

My quetion is: how I can Count result per test_id 
for example to be like this :

**result query**

```
id | test_id    | total_result
====================
1  | 1| A(2)
2  | 2| A(1)
3  | 3| B(1)
```

Thanks

Comment: SELECT id,test_id,COUNT(result) FROM T GROUP BY  id,test_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.test_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(A.result, '(', COUNT(A.id), ')') AS total_result
FROM tb_result A 
GROUP BY A.test_id
```